# Does ALGLIB RBF support dimension higher than 3 (4D, 5D or higher dimension)?

Tags: c#, interpolation, alglib

Does ALGLIB RBF support dimension higher than 3 (4D, 5D or higher dimension)?

http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/fastrbf.php states that it supports 2D and 3D. So does the current code in ALGLIB 3.9.

I would like to confirm the answer, and check if ALGLIB RBF is going to support higher dimension interpolation (4D, 5D or higher) in the future release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up after much further research

No, [ALGLIB RBF](http://www.alglib.net/interpolation/fastrbf.php) (as of v3.9) doesn't support high dimensional interpolation (4D, 5D or higher).

I ended up using [Scipy RBF](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) which is verified running 4D interpolation. I didn't have the chance to verify 5D or higher dimension.

This [Scipy RBF Tutorial](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/RadialBasisFunctions) is very useful to setup a quick working prototype.